# Does Rails have to lazy load everything? Or does it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I notice things like: 0.15s in my specs for a simple method like:

```
class String
  def to_slug
    (self.dup).gsub(/["']/, '').gsub(/@/, 'at').gsub(/&/, 'and').parameterize
  end
end
```

I start to ask myself what is going on, so after benching the method without parameterize I decided this was a problem inside of parameterize and not necessarily with the method itself but, well, with the way it's loaded, it seems to me like it's lazily loaded when Monkey Patches like that should be eager loaded, it is causing latency where it should not exist IMO.  So my questions are, does Rails really lazily load the file that contains parameterize and is there way to convince Rails to eager load patches to String and other stdlib's.

Comment: This will only make a difference for the very first call to a method after starting the rails environment (that is when it's "cold"), i.e. it will have absolutely no impact for a "hot" environment. I can't imagine a scenario where the mentioned first call would be important.

Comment: i can't think of a way for rails to lazy load methods like this. the lazy loading is usually done with autoload which is triggered when constants like String are defined. what exactly did you see there?

Comment: @phoet I assume there is a lazy load somewhere because when I remove parameterize the function speeds speeds up to well below 0.0001 seconds per run,  it could be that it's not directly related to parameterize but a Class that it or one of the functions it uses calls and gets lazy loaded.  I'd have to run a trace or check the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `config.threadsafe!` in your `config/environments/test.rb` should force all code to be loaded at boot time. Note that this will set `cache_classes` to `true`, so don't use it in `development` environment or you will lose code reloading.

Another way would be to change `config.eager_load_paths` to include the directory you want to load.

#### Resources:

- Aaron Patterson explains `config.threadsafe!` in his article [Removing config.threadsafe!](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/06/18/removing-config-threadsafe.html).
- The [Rails guide on configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) has a lot of information on each option.